# pi tries to launch Python script only when booting to CLI

Tags: raspbian, boot

If I change my config to autologin to the CLI using raspi-config I get an error at the end of the boot sequence:

~$ python3: can't open file 'home/pi/path_to_old_script/script.py

I have checked:

1. /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
2. /etc/rc.local
3. crontab -e

It does not seem to occur when I boot to the GUI/Desktop.

I am not sure where this is being called from.

Is there anywhere else I could have added it that I have forgotten that would cause it to run at startup?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Don’t put GUI scripts in rc.local (indeed don’t put anything)

Comment: What's the question? How to avoid the error message? How to make the script running?

Comment: I edited my initial post, but I am not sure where this is being called from.

Is there anywhere else I could have added it that I have forgotten that would cause it to run at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other places to check for startup scripts on Raspbian (assuming that is what you are using), one of them being SystemD. If you type systemctl it will list things configured for systemd. There may also be files in the older `/etc/init.d` folder, although these are no longer used in recent Raspbian versions.

Other places scripts can be started are a `.bashrc`, situated in the home directory of a user, which would run every time a new bash prompt is started and `/etc/profile` which is also run every time a new bash session is created.